# While making an code using python smtplib and selenium i got this type of error

Tags: python

Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="main_table_countries"]/tbody[1]"}
  (Session info: chrome=)

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Well, errors are fine. You should see at what line of code the error points and re-read and re-analyze your code around this line. If you would like us to help, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.